# How do I make a loop use results from the last iteration

Tags: python-3.x, function, numpy, for-loop

I'm trying to write a loop that will use the previous results for position and velocity in the next iteration of the loop

The inputs of the function are a 1D mass array, 2D position array, 2D velocity array, total time value, and step size.  Here's the code:

```
def calculateTrajectories(masses, positions, velocities, time, dt):

    startP = positions
    startV = velocities



    Pdt = np.array([startP])
    Vdt = np.array([startV])
    Times = np.array([time])   


    for i in range(0,time+dt,dt):


        VandP = updateParticles(masses,Pdt[i-1],Vdt[i-1],i)
        P = VandP[0]
        V = VandP[1]

        np.append(Pdt,P)
        np.append(Vdt,V)


        t = i 

        np.append(Times,t)



    return Times, Pdt, Vdt
```

When I test it I get this error:

[error message](https://i.stack.imgur.com/MDP3O.png)

Comment: `Pdt` and `Vdt` start as (1,) shape arrays, and nothing changes that.  `np.append` is **not** a list append clone.  You don't show `time` or `dt`, but I'm guessing that `range` is not stepping `0,1,2,...`   You need to start an interactive `python` session, and experiment with running simple `for` loops, looking at values at each step along the way.  Develop and debug code in small steps, testing every step.

Comment: Please post a textual error